# Give macro to other view controller to make an cgrectmake

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros, cgrectmake

I have a view controller with level selection. if i click on level 1 i want to commit a macro to my gameviewcontroller with the numbers of buttons per row.

for example:

for this one:

```
  *  *  *  *  *
*  *  *  *  *  *
  *  *  *  *  * 
*  *  *  *  *  *
```

i want to commit 5,6,5,6

for this one:

```
*  *  *  *  *
*  *  *
*  *  *  *  * 
*  *
```

i want to commit 5,3,5,2

and so on.

with

```
-(void) generateButtons {
int positionsLeftInRow = BUTTONS_PER_ROW;
int j = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < [self.Model.buttons count]; i++) {
NSInteger value = ((Model *)self.Model.buttons[i]).value;

ButtonView *cv = [[ButtonView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((i % BUTTONS_PER_ROW) * 121 + (i % BUTTONS_PER_ROW) * 40 + 205, j * 122 + j * 40 + 320, 125, 125) andPosition:i andValue:value];

if (!((Model *)self.Model.buttons[i]).outOfPlay) {
    [self.boardView addSubview:cv];


    if ([self.Model.usedButtons containsObject: self.Model.buttons[i]]) {

        [self.usedButtons addObject: cv];

        [cv flip];

    }
}

if (--positionsLeftInRow == 0) {
    j++;
    positionsLeftInRow = BUTTONS_PER_ROW;
}
}
```

i can create a button view. j = rows. if j=1 its my second row. i can make a if (j = 1) {positionsLeftInRow = BUTTONS_PER_ROW -1; } but it isnt really working for commiting by another view controller.. i think i need something different then BUTTON_PER_ROW. so i thought i commit 5,5,5,5 or something and implement this for my code in the gameviewcontroller.

i hope you can understand my problem...
thanks!

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to describe. More like "[**word salad**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_salad)" than Sausage salad, I'm afraid. "Commit a macro?" What does that even mean?

Comment: Sry. I mean i have a viewcontroller with levels (1-10) when i click on button 1 (for level1) i want to commit code to a other viewcontroller (to the controller where i want to make the cgrectmake) in this viewcontroller should be up to 4 rows with buttons. and when my levelviewcontroller commit 5,5,5,5 to the gameviewcontroller, the gameviewcontroller should know, row 1 = 5 buttons, row 2 = 5 buttons, row 3 = 5 buttons and row4 = 5 buttons. is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As written your question is very unclear. Your use of the words "commit" and "macro" are confusing, and "but it isnt really working" also does not help.Please try to focus your question on what you want the output of this function to be and what it is instead. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask